# while loop not being executed on iOS

Tags: unity, ios, advertisements

So I have this code for showing an ad. It is supposed to pause the app while the ad  is showing. It works on android but on iOS it doesn't even seem to be called, judging from the debug msgs shown in Xcode. Here is the code :

```
IEnumerator ShowAndWaitForAd()
{
    if (Advertisement.IsReady())
    {
        Debug.Log("Add is ready");
        ShowOptions options = new ShowOptions();
        options.resultCallback = AdCallbackhandler;
        Advertisement.Show();
    }
    else {
        Debug.Log("Add is not ready");
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(2);
        GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform.FindChild("Loading").gameObject.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
    float currentTimeScale = Time.timeScale;
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
    Debug.Log ("From show Ad, current time scale is: " + Time.timeScale);
    Debug.Log ("current status of advertisement is : " + Advertisement.isShowing);
    while (Advertisement.isShowing) {
        Debug.Log ("!!!!!!Ad is showing!!!!!!");
        yield return null;
    }
    SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(2);
    GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform.FindChild("Loading").gameObject.SetActive(true);

    Debug.Log ("Setting timescale to 1!!!!!");
    Time.timeScale = currentTimeScale;
}
```

On android this starts loading the level only after the ad has finished or has been skipped. On iOS this load the level while the ad is showing. That means that the line `while (Advertisement.isShowing)` is being skipped for some reason. Has anyone encountered this before ?

Edit the problem seems to be that `Advertisement.isShowing` is always returning false even when the ad is showing.

Comment: Maybe try to avoid running more code after Show, and rather use the callback function from the Show()
var options = new ShowOptions { resultCallback = HandleShowResult };
        Advertisement.Show(RewardedZoneId, options);

Comment: @sphair Thats how I ultimately solved it but I just want to know why it has a different behavior on iOS and Android :D